# Dependency and synchronization in Ngrx effect (API) calls

Tags: ngrx

My component needs data from the API.
It lets the store dispatches an action, but before dispatching this action some other data needs to be obtained first. Thus, dispatched action is dependent on data that needs to be fetched before the actual action is called and the fetched data is passed to the action.

```
this.d1 = this.store.pipe(select(selectData1));
this.d2 = this.store.pipe(select(selectData2));
// ...
// dispatch the actions below to and pass identifier (id) in order to get its object from the API and put the fetched data in store.
this.store.dispatch(action1({data1Id}));
this.store.dispatch(action1({data2Id}));

// dispatch the actual action and pass this.d1 and this.d2
this.store.dispatch(targetAction({this.d1, this.d2}));
```

What is the best practise for the situation described above?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to subscribe to `this.d1` and `this.d2` and then dispatch the target action when they emit:

```
combineLatest([this.d1 this.d2])
  .subscribe(([d1, d2]) => {
    if (d1 && d2) {
      this.store.dispatch(targetAction(d1, d2));
    }
  })
```

However, it might be better to use an effect for this:
https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

Comment: Thanks Steve, as AMOF I am using an effect to fetch the information (targetAction) from my API. But also the effects for fetching d1 and d2. I find your proposition with combineLatest a very logical one. You are serializing the actions and there it is guaranteed that the actions for fetching d1 and d2 occur before the fetch of targetAction. And, it only happens if d1 and d2 exists (the if guard).